# How do I configure Excel's cell fill colour to allow the default cell grid to show through?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

In Excel (2013), if I set the cell fill colour for an adjacent group of cells, the cell fill colour hides the default cell grid lines. For example:

[image]

I know I can format these cells and set the inside and outside borders but that's a somewhat tedious task, especially where I'm using lots of different fills on a large workbook with many worksheets.

Is there a way to set cell fill colours to become transparent insofar as allowing the default grid lines to be displayed?

Comment: I don't think so. The fill color will overlap the border, and any border painted will overlap the fill color. You could use a fill which is only partially filled (a pattern) but it will look bad and then the grid is only partially shown.

Comment: @LPChip - Yeah, I'm rapidly approaching that conclusion, but thought I may as well ask here first before resigning myself to having to fiddle with borders manually.Thanks for taking a look though.

Comment: Little tip, maybe it helps. If you select one cell and the Format Cells and choose the Fill color/pattern and Borders, you can select the other cells and press F4. It is a shortcut that repeats the last action. Maybe it saves a little time adding the borders.

Comment: Could you use conditional formatting?

Comment: It seems like it might be possible to have a VBA routine that would go through your sheet(s) looking for cells that are filled but don't have a defined border, and fix them.  If that approach is acceptable to you, [edit] your question to say so. Also, are you currently using direct formatting or conditional formatting (or both)?